# Why does operator-> overloading not work in VC2010?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
class A
{
public:
    A* operator->() const
    {
    }
    void Test() {}
};
```

then call it like this.

```
A* a = new A;
a->Test();
```

The code builds and runs successfully in VC2010. It seems very strange. I am wondering it is by design or it is a bug of VC2010?

Thanks

Comment: "the code builds and runs" - so what is the problem?

Comment: So does it or does it not work?

Comment: As you see, "operator->" returns nothing. I think the compiler should report error on this.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: I think he's expecting the code to not compile since he redefined the `->` operator.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't calling your `operator->` in your example, you are calling `Test` directly from an `A*`. You want:

```
(*a)->Test();
```

Or...

```
A a;
a->Test();
```

There's nothing wrong with VS2010 concerning `operator->` (that I know of).

Using `->` on a pointer named `a` effectively executes: `(*a).`. Using `->` on a variable by value will invoke your `operator->` if present, or be a syntax error if there is no `operator->`.

Comment: Why "a->Test()" doesn't call "operator->", would you please kindly explain?

Comment: @wyfeizj I added a brief explanation

Comment: You can think of it that way: A* a; a->Test(); means that you're using the operator-> that is defined for a pointer-to-A! But you only overloaded your operator-> for A. A* and A are different types.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is:

```
A* a = new A;
a->Test();
```

The "a" is a pointer to an A.  It is NOT an A object itself, it is a memory address of the A object on the heap.

When you call `a->Test()` you invoke the pointer's -> operator (built in for all pointer types in C++).  You would have to do this to invoke your operator:

```
//Create an A (NOT a pointer).
A a;

//Invoke the A's operator ->
a->Test();
```

Which is how STL iterators work - they're class types, not pointers to class types.  Note that the return type of operator -> must make sense for the operation/member you're trying to invoke.

So, here's an example that would call test via the ->:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A* operator->()
    {
        return this;
    }
    void Test() { std::cout << "Hello World!"; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a->Test();
}
```

It's strange, but it works because `a->Test();` returns the current object, which `Test()` is then called on (see the `return this;` line).

See STL iterators for useful examples of why you'd actually want to do this.